# Printing copies in parallel from web to wide format printer

Tags: digital-printing

I need to print a document that renders to a web browser on a wide format printer (Canon TA-20). The document is long and narrow. I need to print multiple copies at once side-by-side (see simplified image below).

Is there a way to do this without altering the HTML to render each element of the *highly complex* document multiple times side-by-side?[image]

Comment: Do you mean printing directly from the browser? That's not really something graphic designers deal with. If I were to do this I would try to move the problem into a sphere where I feel in control. Perhaps first print the webpage to a PDF and then place multiple copies of that PDF in InDesign (or a free alternative like Scribus or maybe InkScape). Maybe you could even use Acrobat to place three copies of the PDF side by side, not sure about that.

Comment: @Wolff The problem with generating a PDF is that the SVG images are being rasterized. I need to send the vector graphics directly to the printer as vectors or find some other solution to preserve quality.

Comment: You need to define a bit more "highly complex document".

Comment: I think it depends on how you print to PDF and in which browser. I'm using Brave Browser (should be similar to Chrome) and when I in the print dialog set *Destination* to *Adobe PDF* (some) text and SVG files get rasterized, but if I set it to *Save as PDF* it seems to preserve vector graphics.